# Javascript Alert and stay on the current page

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to create some alert with javascript and if i press ok it will stay on the current page. I have try but if i use below javascript it will give the alert and it move in other page.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Maps not available");
window.close();
</script>';
```

Please help :)

Here is my detail code.

```
if ($decoded['VEHICLE']['RESULT'] == 'OK') {

        $arr = $decoded['VEHICLE']['DATA']; 

            if ($arr != NULL) {
                $encoded = json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

                $decoded_again = json_decode($encoded, TRUE);


                $line = array();
                foreach($decoded_again as $item) { 
                     array_push($line, $item['LAT'].','.$item['LON']);
                }                   
                return $line;
            } else {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Maps not available");
                        </script>';             
            }   
    } else {
        redirect('Badvertisers/showMap', 'gpsidnotfound');
    }
```

in earlier i use this method, it will stay on the current page, but with refreshing the page.

Modification of url helper

```
case 'tracknotfound'    : echo "<script>alert('Maps not Available'); 
                          document.location.href='".$uri."'; </script>\n";
            break;
```

and i put this one above controller

```
else {
        redirect('Badvertisers/showMap', 'tracknotfound');          
}
```

Comment: search `confirm()` of javascript

Comment: Delete your `window.close()` ... ?

Comment: @aldrin27 Why use confirm ? He don't speak about cancel action or have 2 actions ... ?

Comment: @Alexis it just one action button, if i press that button it will stay on the current page, it just shown alert notif

Comment: I know, why there's a redirect ? Can you show your code ? Here there's no redirect action

Comment: @Alexis please find above my code, i'm using codeigniter actually, that code above is from my controller

Comment: Try to add `return false;` under your echo

Comment: @Alexis i've try your suggestion but it still on next page, it doesn't stay on the current page.

echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Maps not available");</script>'; return false;

Comment: Ok it's because it don't go in the else part. You've some problem with your test. $decoded != 'ok'

Comment: @alexis i don't get it, can you show me your suggestion code by using an answer in below instead of comment :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112865/discussion-between-alexis-and-amir-rachman).

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `window.close();` and after you press ok will remain the page.

`window.close();` will close the back after you press ok

Comment: i've try this, but still move forward into the next page, it doesn't stay on the current page

Comment: we need to see more code.
I think you might do that on a submit form or something like that.

Try to use a `return(false);`

Like this :

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Maps not available");
return(false)
</script>';`

Comment: i've try that but still moving forward on the next page, anyway please find above my code, i'm using codeigniter actually, that code above is from my controller

Comment: I don't think this is the solution but try it.

`window.history.back()`

Comment: your solution it's working but that one is reloading the page (current page), it same with my ways, redirect('Badvertisers/showMap', 'tracknotfound'); i want go to current page without reloading, is there a way for that ?

Comment: @Amir Rachman i think i got your error.
The thing is that for checking if map exists you are doing a submit to a php, and in this way it's imposible to don't reload the page.

The solution you are lucking for it's called ajax.
instead of submiting to your php file you have to do a ajax request and after getting the request you show the alert you want to.
This will not reaload your page ;)

Hope it helped


http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's `confirm()`:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
checkConfirm = confirm("Maps not available");
if(!checkConfirm){
    window.close(); //This will close the page if "ok" is not selected
}
</script>';
```

Comment: i've try this, but still move forward into the next page, it doesn't stay on the current page

Comment: What are you pressing in the confirm alert?

Comment: i press Ok button, in that case only 1 button, only Ok button, i've given extra code on the above